# How to map absolutely safety backend data after a request?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, architecture, mapping

First I want to say that this scenario can also be in the other way too.

**Scenario:** 
Backend developer is not your friend :D defines a DTO (send JSON) with properties for example in JAVA --> he doesn't communicate with you --> of course not best practise.

**Common problem:**
As a frontend developer with ANGULAR I want to be safe, when I try mapping the backend data to my frontend model (get JSON) --> because I expect this is the point which is definitely often underestimated.

**Normal case**
JSON Object mapping these things which fits --> Wow, what a technique,
but I cannot be safe to have the data in a complete other point in my program.

**Question**
Is there a method or pattern that I get a runtime or compile-time error **during the mapping process** --> that I can be sure, yes the model is definitely exact the same object (JSON model) like the response data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that I also faced and from what I could understand there is no standard pattern yet to solve this in an easy, clean and elegant way.

The easiest and dirtiest thing would be to check that the incoming JSON has only the properties contained in the model that you expect, if one unexpected property is found (so it's undefined on your model instance instead of null) an error can be thrown. It could be achieved with a generic recursive function to take in account nested data structures, iterating on the objects keys.

Another more elegant but more complex method would be the one explained in this article: [TypeScript Json Mapper](http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/), alongside the [reflect-metadata api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) to make it work in angular2+